# How can follow DRY principle for business code

Tags: c#, dry

Consider this code:

```
    public void AddPrice(int exchangeTypeId, decimal price)
    {
        GoldPrice lastPriceValue = UnitOfWork.GoldPrice.Last(x => x.GoldId == exchangeTypeId);
        if (lastPriceValue == null || lastPriceValue.Value != price)
        {
            UnitOfWork.GoldPrice.Add(
                new GoldPrice
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    EntryDate = DateTime.Now,
                    Value = price,
                    GoldId = exchangeTypeId,
                }
                );
        }
        else
        {
            lastPriceValue.EntryDate = DateTime.Now;
        }

        UnitOfWork.Commit();
    }
```

in above code i have some business for example check null,get last price and ....So consider this :

```
    public void AddPrice(int exchangeTypeId, decimal price)
    {

        CurrencyPrice lastPriceValue = UnitOfWork.CurrencyPrice.Last(x => x.CurrencyId == exchangeTypeId);
        if (lastPriceValue == null || lastPriceValue.Value != price)
        {
            UnitOfWork.CurrencyPrice.Add(
                new CurrencyPrice
                    {
                        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                        EntryDate = DateTime.Now,
                        Value = price,
                        CurrencyId = exchangeTypeId,
                    }
                );
        }
        else
        {
            lastPriceValue.EntryDate = DateTime.Now;
        }

        UnitOfWork.Commit();
    }
```

I have tow functions that have exactly same business.if the business change i should change every add price function So how can i follow **DRY** principle for business code?

Comment: Do GoldPrice and CurrencyPrice inherit from a common ancestor or implement a same interface?

Comment: Jefri, I'm not asking you to change their definitions but just to check whether they have a common ancestor (F12 is your friend ;))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could refactor out a base set of abstractions for getting the Price.

```
public interface IPrice
{
    string Id { get; set; }
    DateTime EntryDate { get; set; }
    decimal Value { get; set; }
    int ExchangeTypeId { get; set; }
}

public interface IUnitOfWork<T>
    where T: IPrice
{
    T GetLatest(int exchangeTypeId);
    void Add(T price);
    void Commit();
}

public interface IUnitOfWorkFactory
{
    void Register<T>() where T: IPrice;
    IUnitOfWork<T> Get<T>() where T: IPrice;
}

public void AddPrice<T>(int exchangeTypeId, decimal price)
    where T: IPrice, new()
{
    IUnitOfWork<T> unitOfWork = _unitOfWorkFactory.Get<T>();
    IPrice lastPriceValue = unitOfWork.GetLatest(exchangeTypeId);

    if (lastPriceValue == null || lastPriceValue.Value != price)
    {
        unitOfWork.Add(
            new T
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                EntryDate = DateTime.Now,
                Value = price,
                ExchangeTypeId = exchangeTypeId,
            });
    }
    else
    {
        lastPriceValue.EntryDate = DateTime.Now;
    }

    unitOfWork.Commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

Comment: In general, link-only answers are discouraged.  Try adding a summary of what's contained in the link.

Comment: Especially since links can go bad.